# Probabilistic model of neural network

Tags: machine-learning, probability, neural-networks

I read Neil's [presentation](http://inverseprobability.com/talks/slides/2017-12-04-deep-probabilistic-modelling-with-gaussian-processes.slides.html) and found this joint model is confusing:
$$p(y_*|y, X, x_*) = \int p(y_*|x_*, W)p(W|y, X)dW $$
where $W$ contains $W_1$ and $W_2$ and $p(W|y,X)$ is posterior density

Can anyone explain it to me?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_predictive_distribution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have the uncertainty of your prediction, think in risk involved applications, autonomous driving, clinical studies, finance etc.
Check this Yarin Gal post about his work in Bayesian NN 
http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/yarin/blog_2248.html

Hope it helps

Comment: It theoretically explained why dropout works, I wonder is there any other practical benefit we can get other than dropout?

Comment: If dropout help generalization, should we use it as much as possible?

Comment: Well I use it most of the time for regularization, I found it helps in situations of small data, contrary to the common belief that Deep NN are for big data, in small data sets NN tend to memoryze the data (overfit), using  dropout helps a lot.

Answer (score 3):

ML people are forced to use these fancy notations to keep the programmers at bay. Otherwise their field would be easily overtaken by hordes of programmers overnight.

All this means is that you estimate the weights $W$ from the training sample (y,X), then given these weights calculate the test predictions $y^*$ from the test sample $x^*$. The probability notation emphasizes that somehow you obtain not just the estimate of the weight $W$, but it's conditional probability distribution $p(W\mid y,X)$

Once you know this probability distribution, you can calculate the probability distribution of the predicted value $p(y^*\mid x^*,W)$ that is conditional on the weights and test features $x^*$, it's just the formula $$P(A)=\sum_iP(A|B_i)P(B_i)$$

I'm expecting angry comments about likelihoods vs probability densities.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, may I know your understanding of what benefit the probabilistic model brings in solving practical problem?

Comment: The formula you're citing there represents the law of total probability, not Bayes' rule/law/theorem, which is $P(A|B)=\frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}$.

Comment: The neural nets are probabilistic frameworks inside, but to use them you don't need to be a statistician. The benefit is that you're probably dealing with stochastic processes in practice. For instance, in machine vision there's noise in every pixel, it comes both from the environment and from the circuitry/hardware of the cameras and equipment. Another example is when you design image recognition, you need to train the system on a dataset, which involves some random sampling. In other words we have to deal with randomness of some kind all the time, and probabilistic approaches are well suited